# Tdd parsing node value errors

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, tdd

I am trying to create a test to parse the distance value of the google distance matrix api.  Right now its all in a string just so I dont have to make a connection to the api(posted a link to xml readout.  I am having a problem parsing the value of a node.  I put everything in a string.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Muncie&destinations=Miami&language=en-EN&sensor=false&language=en-EN&units=imperial

Here is my test when I run it I get null as the result instead of 64275

```
public class GoogleDistanceMatrixXMLTest {

private static final String DISTANCE_XML_STRING = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><DistanceMatrixResponse><status>OK</status><origin_address>Muncie, IN, USA</origin_address><destination_address>Miami, FL, USA</destination_address><row><element><status>OK</status><duration><value>64275</value><text>17 hours 51 mins</text></duration><distance><value>1961951</value><text>1,219 mi</text></distance></element></row></DistanceMatrixResponse>";

private Document document;

@Before
public void setUp() throws ParserConfigurationException,
SAXException, IOException{
    InputSource source = createInputSourceFromSampleXMLData();
    document = parseXMLFrom(source);
}

private InputSource createInputSourceFromSampleXMLData() {
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(DISTANCE_XML_STRING);
    return new InputSource(stringReader);
}

private Document parseXMLFrom(InputSource source) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return documentBuilder.parse(source);
}
@Test
public void testRetrieveDurationValue() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    String durationChildNodeValue = document.getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(3).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    Assert.assertEquals("64275", durationChildNodeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String durationChildNodeValue = document.getFirstChild()...;
```

should be

```
String durationChildNodeValue = document.getDocumentElement()...;
```

There's no guarantee the document element is the first child.  The processing instruction is likely the first child.